# PHP: How to determine email attachment's MIME type?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mime-types, zend-mail

I'm using Zend's `Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3` to connect to mail server, open an email, and iterate through its attachments. If the attachment is a PDF, I need to download it. At each iteration of each message part, I call the `getHeaders` and use Regex to determine the mime type of the attachment. In most cases, I get something like this:

```
["content-type"]=> string(64) "application/octet-stream; name=abc.pdf"
["content-transfer-encoding"]=> string(6) "base64"
```

But in some cases, I get something like this:

```
multipart/mixed; boundary=--boundary_2_1dca5b3b-499e-4109-b074-d8b5f914404a
```

How do I determine the mime type of such attachments?

Comment: Can it be that you have encountered the famous Microsoft TNEF attachment format? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format)

Comment: Looks like `Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3` is unable to parse the email. You might want to use the Mailparse extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php or the Imap extension http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: I posted a fairly lengthy explanation of how to parse the raw email to find the parts, but an extension might be a good starting point.  You can look at `php-mime-mailparser`:  http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

Comment: Pear has a mime parser as well: [Pear PHP `Mail_mimeDecode`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit of a complicated case.  When the `content-type` is `multipart/mixed` that means that there are several pieces of the email.  One or more of these might be an attachment (in addition to possibly including an html region or plain text).

When the `content-type` is `multipart/mixed`, a boundary is also given.  You can use this regex to determine if you are dealing with a multipart email:

```
$contentType = $this->GetHeader('content-type');
$regex = '%multipart.*?boundary\s*=\s*"?(\w+)?"?%is';
$matches = array();

if (preg_match($regex, $contentType, $matches)) {
    $this->isMultiPart = true;
    $this->boundary = $matches[1];
} else {
    $this->isMultiPart = false;
}
```

(note that this sample is part of a larger class dealing with email messages)

If your message is a multipart email, the next step is to separate all of the parts.  You can do this like so:

```
$parts = explode("--$this->boundary", $this->fullBody);
```

The boundary always will start with `--` per the email standards.  Then the only thing left to do is to parse each of the individual parts.
You probably already have code to do that.  Each part will have the same headers that you mentioned in your question: `content-type` and `content-transfer-encoding`.
There might be other part headers as well, and you will want to remove them (they will all start with the prefix `content` if I remember correctly).
Then make sure that if the part is base64 encoded that you account for that (you can check the `content-transfer-encoding` header to determine this.
The mime-type of the individual attachment will be stored in the part's `content-type` header just like in the case of a single part message.

One note - this assumes that you are dealing with the raw source of the message.  To do this, you can use `getRawHeader` and `getRawContent`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the Zend library exposes a `isMultipart()` method. I use that to determine if the email might have attachments. I begin looping at the *second* `Zend_Mail_Message` part (as I *think* that is where the attachments start; the first part being the actual email). Is this right?

Comment: Is `fullBody` a Zend method? I want to try out your solution.

Comment: Generally that is the way to do it, but it seems like in your case there was some sort of error in the Zend framework.  From what you said, it seems like `isMultipart()` is returning `true`, but then once you look at the message part it is still saying that it is multipart.  

So basically, whatever is returning the `multipart/mixed` should be analyzed as above, and that will (hopefully!) give you the individual parts.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a full body method, but the full body is really just `getHeaders() . "\n\n" . getRawContent()`  (the headers, two line breaks then the content).

Comment: Again, I would _highly_ recommend checking out a prepackaged extension that does this - I've used [MimeMailParser](http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/) in the past with some success.

Comment: I'm not on the Zend framework. Just using its libraries. The method that gives me the `multipart/mixed; boundary=--boundary_2_1dca5b3b-499e-4109-b074-d8b5f914404a` is Zend_Mail_Part->getHeaders(). I see what other methods it might expose.